# PowerShell ConvertTo-CSV end of line issue when sending to other items

Tags: powershell

I make a pscustom object which looks like so

```
PS C:\...\acc> $csv

Count NonExistentUser
----- ---------------
1sht  1sht           
2sht  21sht
```

I convert it

```
$csv = $csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I upload it

```
$upload= Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $SessionHeader -Method Post -Uri $attachUri  -Body $csv -ContentType 'multipart/form-data'
```

The upload works but the csv on the other end .... the whole csv is all on the same line
when you download the csv from any other portal that stores attachments.

the output csv that is always uploaded is always on one line

```
"Count","NonExistentUser" "1sht","1sht" "2sht","21sht"
```

How do I add the link breaks to the end of each line before sending or converting?

Comment: updated for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

```
# $csv is an array of *custom objects*.
# If you send those to ConvertTo-Csv, you'll get an *array* of lines,
# which you must explicitly join to form a *single, multiline string*
# in order to pass it to -Body below.
$csvData = ($csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join "`n"

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $SessionHeader -Method Post -Body $csvData -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Uri $attachUri
```

As an aside:

- By default, in *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x*, [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) uses character encoding [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC%208859-1) (almost identical to [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), with a few characters missing) to encode strings in requests.

  - Fortunately, PowerShell *7.4+* now defaults to UTF-8.
- To use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) instead, append `;charset=utf-8` to the `-ContentType` argument (e.g.,
  `-ContentType 'application/json;charset=utf-8'`.

---

It **looks like your only problem** was that your (final) **`$csv`** value, which is an ***array* of lines** - because that's what [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) emits - was passed to `-Body` *as-is*, which caused `Invoke-RestMethod` to  *implicitly stringify* the array.

**When PowerShell automatically stringifies an array, its elements are *space-concatenated***,<sup>[1]</sup> resulting in a *single-line* representation.

A simple example, using an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), which applies the same stringification:

```
PS> $lines = 'one', 'two'; "$lines"
one two
```

Therefore, in order **to pass your CSV data as a *multi-line* string**, as intended, you must explicitly **join the array elements with newlines first**, as shown above, via **`-join`**, the [string-joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)

---

<sup>[1] Spaces are used by default; it is technically possible - but rarely done in practice - to specify a different separator via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

ok this applies to almost everything PowerShell in-memory ... you use the pnpsharepoint module ... you use invoke-restmethod ... your going to love this.

You have a csv and you dont want to write to disk .. because .. why would anyone ever want to write to disk.... and you tested but ...

Now I know you already tested writting it to disk and are really mad that MS didnt provide a -encoding utf8 to converto-csv

```
we never ever want to write to disk in code because who has a disk available
Export-Csv -Encoding utf8 -path <i in no way want to save to disk>
```

```
invoke-restmethod -infile $csv 
or
    $stream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($CSV))
    $attachmentInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCreationInformation 
    $attachmentInfo.FileName = $fileName
    $attachmentInfo.ContentStream = $stream
    $attchedFile = $listItem.AttachmentFiles.Add($attachmentInfo)
```

yeah it keeps removing your end of line character .. here you go

```
$csv = @()
            $csv += [pscustomobject]@{
                Count = '1sht'
                NonExistentUser = '1sht'
            }
            $csv += [pscustomobject]@{
                Count = '2sht'
                NonExistentUser = '21sht'
            }
```

now convert that before you use it

```
$csv = $csv | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | out-string
$csv = $csv -replace "`r`n","`n"
```

Now use that new $csv variable ... cheers

Comment: If you use PowerShell Core, almost everything defaults to UTF8 no BOM

Comment: `ConvertTo-Csv` outputs _strings_, and PowerShells strings are always .NET strings (internally composed of UTF-16 Unicode code units). Using a different character encoding only applies when communicating with the outside world. Therefore an `-Encoding` parameter isn't appropriate for `ConvertTo-Csv`, but it is for cmdlets that write to a _file_, such as `Export-Csv` for instance.

Comment: To control the encoding of strings for inclusion in requests sent by `Invoke-RestMethod`, append something like `;charset=utf-8` to the `-ContentType` parameter; e.g. `-ContentType 'application/json;charset=utf-8'`